# Automation of SQL query

Tags: mysql, excel

I have recently started working as an Analyst.Part of my job is to run SQL queries on a daily basis and paste the results in an Excel sheet. This sometime becomes tedious. I would like to automate this process i.e. the SQL query should run automatically and the result set(s) should be copied automatically into an Excel sheet(path will be specified by me). Can I do this? If yes, then how?

P.S. We use SQLyog(Open Source) to run SQL queries and Microsoft Excel 2010 to paste and show data.

Comment: yes, it can be done. You can program Excel to access the DB directly and insert the records in.

Answer (score 1):

You could always export your data as comma separated result and open it in Excel.
Even if your tools does not support it could be easily created a column that is a concatenation of all your columns comma separated.
Then save automatically result as a .csv file to open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the data publication process, I think a better way is to use 'cron' to schedule you daily query in a shell script, and store the csv data file in a certain directory or send it to your mailbox.